# Why does the induced EMF of a moving rod change on changing frame of reference?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I have the following question

[image]

The solution to the problem is

[image]

But I wanted to do this question in a different way. I considered the frame of reference as the bottom part of the rod(which can be imagined as the observer sitting on the bottom part of rod) . Therefore the top part of the rod will now be seen as having velocity $v_2-v_1$.

Taking a small portion of rod with length $dx$ I can write

$$\int_0^\epsilon d\epsilon=\int_0^L BV dx$$

Since $v=r\omega$

$$\epsilon=\int_0^\epsilon Bx\omega dx$$

$$\epsilon=[\frac{B\omega x^2}{2}]_0^L$$

$$\epsilon=\frac{B\omega L^2}{2}$$

Since velocity of the top most part of rod is $v_2-v_1$

$$\epsilon= \frac{B(v_2-v_1) L^2}{2L}$$

$$\epsilon= \frac{B(v_2-v_1)L}{2}$$

Why is the induced EMF lesser?

Answer (score 1):

In that reference frame there is also an electric field $\textbf v_1\times\textbf B$ and the integral of that along the rod supplies the part of the emf that you are missing. (You should check this, and make sure the sign is correct!)